# ComplexType Properties Array Bug

Tags: breeze

I found a bug concerning the ComplexType properties. I have an Object which has a property which is a collection of other objects which I defined in the client-side metadata as a Complex property, i.e. "isComplexType: true". However all properties of a complex type are set to 'undefined'. I did a bit of debugging and found this:

```
// target and source may not be entities that can also be complexTypes.
function updatePropertyFromRawEntity(dp, target, rawSource) {
    var val = getPropertyFromRawEntity(rawSource, dp);
    if (val === undefined) return;
    if (dp.isComplexProperty) {
        var coVal = target.getProperty(dp.name);
        dp.dataType.dataProperties.forEach(function (cdp) {
            // recursive call
            updatePropertyFromRawEntity(cdp, coVal, val);
        });
    } else {
        target.setProperty(dp.name, val);
    }
}
```

The rawSource parameter is an array(in case of complexTypes) is an array of objects. So the problem is when invoking the getPropertyFromRawEntity(), it passes an array not an object:

```
function getPropertyFromRawEntity(rawEntity, dp) {
    var propName = dp.nameOnServer || dp.isUnmapped && dp.name;
    return parseValueForDp(rawEntity[propName], dp);
}
```

So rawEntity[propName] will always be undefined because its an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Breeze ComplexType has a well defined structure specified by metadata.  Any property, (except) the key can have its datatype be a complexType.  However, what you want, I think, is an "untyped" structure.  This can be accomplished by defining the property as having a data type of  "Undefined", something like:

```
  var newProp = new DataProperty({
                name: "Foo"
                dataType: DataType.Undefined,
                isNullable: true,
                isUnmapped: true
            });
  entityType.addProperty(newProp);
```

The "Undefined" dataType will accept data of any type and structure.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but its not that case. An undefined property will not be an observable, and I need it to be. I also know that the ComplexType has a well defined structure. I'm pretty sure that there is a flaw somewhere in the code. A quick fix will be to check if rawSource is an array and do a foreach loop. However you probably know better than me whats going on inside Breeze. Side question: is there a way to send the whole object-tree back to the server on saveChanges?

Comment: Right now instances of ComplexTypes must be scalar, i.e. they cannot be arrays. We will be relaxing that restriction in a forthcoming release where we offer support for NoSQL databases.  The code for this is nontrivial.  As for sending an entire tree back to the server, the saveChanges method allows you to list the objects that you want saved.  (It's default is to only send added/modified or deleted entities).  So you would need to walk your object graph, (not that hard given that you have the entityMetadata available) and collect the list of entities that you want saved.

Comment: Do you have an estimate when the next release will be published?

Comment: Hopefully within about two-three weeks for the NoSQL support version, there may be bug releases for other issues before that. I will post back here when it gets in.